# Validation for UWP textbox

Tags: validation, uwp

I am currently developing a UWP application, I am very new to this platform and need some help.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you using databinding? or you just going for it? And do you want type as you go validation or validations on a button click?

Comment: Hi! I am using data annotation, and I want the validations on a button click

Comment: Oh that one is quite simple, you use data binding? if yes, i'll share up a quick demo to do so.

Comment: I am sorry but I am quite new to the coding world, but may I know what data binding means? I personally feel that I am not using data binding... because I am creating a form where by the user can enter the information and it get stored in the database. Hence, no updating or editing of data is involved.

Comment: Even better, for forms it's the best way to go, so what I'll do is I'll use data binding and if you feel there is any help regarding the same, you can use the comments section. It'll take much less time for me if i use data binding

Comment: oh okay! Do you need my codes to aid you? To help you better understand what I need?

Comment: Yeah that'll be very useful.

Comment: I have added some codes which I feel that are useful, If you find it too long, you can just proceed to do a demo that you are comfortable with. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Great I'll write something up. gimme some time :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Im sorry to ask for a flavor, I am also trying to do a validation whereby a MessageDialog will show if the user chose a date that is greater than today. It would be great if it is possible for you to do a demo on it as well?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant when I said I'll write something up

Comment: Alright! Thanks!

Comment: I'll put up an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to write up a demo project.

You can find it on [Github Here!](https://github.com/ImCarrot/FormValidatorDemoStack)

I'll quickly tell you about the sample, There are two solutions:

1. Quick and Dirty: This took the most time for me and I had to write up a lot of code for something very trivial. I don't recommend this way but this way is non complicated and straight forward.
2. Dynamic Content way (Recommended): Here, I've kept things extensible might be a little bit complex but it's more easy to manage and works much better than the first way.

Since you're using `MVVM`, I've followed the same.

**Please Note:** I haven't exactly replicated your model as I didn't know what to put in the UI and what all are the validations, but from the sample you'll be able to figure it out.

I hope this helps, in-case of any queries, feel free to use the comments section.

In the recommended solution your key area to control is just a single collection:

```
internal ObservableCollection<ComponentModel.IFormControl> FormFields => new ObservableCollection<ComponentModel.IFormControl>(new List<ComponentModel.IFormControl>()
    {
        new ViewModel.TextFieldInputControlViewModel(){HeaderName = "Name",PlaceholderText="e.g. John Doe",IsMandatory = true },
        new ViewModel.TextFieldInputControlViewModel(){HeaderName = "Admin No" , PlaceholderText = "e.g. ABC123"},
        new ViewModel.TextFieldInputControlViewModel(){HeaderName = "Phone" , PlaceholderText = "e.g. +32538349182" ,IsMandatory = true,MatchingPattern = @"^[\+]?[1-9]{1,3}\s?[0-9]{6,11}$"},
        new ViewModel.TextFieldInputControlViewModel(){HeaderName = "Item Description", PlaceholderText = "e.g. My Fav Item",IsMandatory = true },
        new ViewModel.TextFieldInputControlViewModel(){HeaderName = "Location Lost", PlaceholderText = "e.g. Alaska",IsMandatory = true },
        new ViewModel.DateTimeFieldInputViewModel(){ HeaderName = "Date Lost",IsMandatory = true}
    });
```

and you can add more types from inheriting from the interface `IFormControl` and just add in fields here. exactly as simple as it sounds when it comes to adding more fields.