# How to check if textboxes are empty in UWP, using MVVM, and give the user a UI-validation

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, uwp

I'm making a simple sign-in page in UWP, using MVVM, and want to check if each of the textboxes are empty. Next to each textbox, there is a textblock with fontfamily "Wingdings 2".

If the field is empty, I want the textblock to show a red cross (" &#x4F ;"), and if the textbox contains text the textblock should update to show a green check-mark (" &#x50 ;").

*(Note: There are no spaces in the words for the icons, but I had to put the spaces in there, to stop StackOverFlow from formatting the text).*

All textblocks display a red cross by default (when the page is navigated to).

Here is an example picture of how I want it:

[image: Textboxes with icons next to them.]

**Here is my code in the ViewModel:**

```
public string FirstName {
    get{
        return _firstName;
    }
    set{
        if (_firstName == null){
            _firstName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FirstName));
        }
    }
}

public string LastName{
    get{
        return _lastName;
    }
    set{
        if (_lastName == null){
            _lastName = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(LastName));
        }
    }
}
```

How should I bind the textboxes to update icons in the textblocks next to them, when the user starts typing in each field?

Comment: show viewmodel code. You can have bool property on the viewmodel and control the visibility using BoolToVisibilityConverter

Answer (score 1):

Well as it turns out I had worked on a project like a `form validator` for someone on stackoverflow itself.

I had uploaded the sample project for the same on `Git` as [FormValidatorDemoStack](https://github.com/ImCarrot/FormValidatorDemoStack). It's exactly what you need.

### About the Project:

It contains two approaches, one without `MVVM` called the `QuickAndDirty` and the second one using `MVVM` and `UserControls` called the `Recommended`. You can see it from the `splitview` on the right side.

---

### References:

The link to the old question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538144/validation-for-uwp-textbox/46545014#46545014) and the follow up question for extending the validation to multiple inputs in a single field is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258119/validation-for-textbox-with-two-sets-of-phone-numbers/47261015#47261015).

> I hope this helps, if you have any questions feel free to use the
>   comments section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this, is to use TextBoxRegex XAML Property from [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxregex).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)